# Filter with dependent combo box

Tags: excel, vba

Actaully I am creating Inventory Management Macro in VBA
But I am stuck with one problem

I have a productmaster sheet as below  column

```
Sr. No  Product  Purchase Price     Sale Price  Weight
```

Whenever I am selecting same product but changing weight in combo box
Purchase / Sale rate should be change accordingly

but it is taking same rate though I changed the product weight

So can you please tell me what can I do to resolve the same

Below is the coding i have done

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("product_Master")


If Me.com_prod.Value = "" Or Me.com_trantype = "" Then Me.txt_rate.Value = ""

   ''' to filter on the basis of weight
   sh.Range("A1:I32000").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=Me.com_weight.Value
   If Me.com_trantype.Value = "Sale" Then

       On Error Resume Next
       Me.txt_rate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.com_prod, 
       sh.Range("B:E"), 3, 0)

        On Error GoTo 0
   ElseIf Me.com_trantype.Value = "Purchase" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Me.txt_rate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.com_prod, 
        sh.Range("B:E"), 2, 0)
        On Error Resume Next
   End If
```

Comment: Your code misses an `End If`. When you try debugging, `On Error Resume Next` is a bad idea. How to know if an error should occur on the lines after it? In fact, why using it? What " is taking same rate"? The filter criteria?

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru for you suggestions and below is my issue I hope you will understand 
The thing is I am choosing transaction type = sale or purchase and suppose I have same product with two different weight it is showing rate in combo box only for  the first row only though I change the weight in combo box it is not changing accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   Dim sh As Worksheet, col As Long, res

   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("product_Master")

   If Me.com_prod.Value = "" Or Me.com_trantype = "" Then 
       Me.txt_rate.Value = ""
   Else
       '???
   End If 

   ''' to filter on the basis of weight
   sh.Range("A1:I32000").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=Me.com_weight.Value

   Select Case Me.com_trantype.Value
       Case "Sale": col = 3
       Case "Purchase": col = 2
   End Select

   If col > 0 Then
       'no need for error trapping if you drop WorksheetFunction...
       '  you can test the return value instead
       res = Application.VLookup(Me.com_prod, sh.Range("B:E"), col, 0)
       Me.txt_rate.Value = iif(iserror(res), "???", res)
   End If
```

Comment: Hey Tim Thanks for the above answer but problem is not solved yet,
still the same thing happening whenever I am choosing transaction type = sale or purchase  and suppose I have **same product** with two different weight it is showing rate of the first row only though I change the weight in combo box  .So could you try to solve for me again 
Thank you so much !

Comment: Pls share your mail id  I will  send you the macro

Comment: OK I left my mail here for a couple of hours - if you didn't get it then you'll need to put the file on dropbox/box/drive/etc and share a link here

Comment: You will need to provide some steps to replicate the specific problem

Comment: Run the main form and try to add purchase or sale transaction and while adding transaction try to choose a product having two diffrent weight in product master sheet  and once you seleft the weight try to change it and check whether rate value in rate text box  reflecting same value as mentioned in product master excel sheet . And that's the problem

Comment: There's no real code behind the weight combobox?  It doesn't update the rate textbox...

Comment: Yes that's what the issue is I was trying to put but confused I want that rate textbox to update pls do the needful

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to dive in right now.  One thing I would say is you need to make sure you unfilter that product table at some points - otherwise all rows eventually end up filtered out and there's no data to populate your drop-downs

Comment: Yes I will do that but pls help me to solve the issue if possible by tommorow

Comment: Hey TIM can you pls help me out on the above ??

Comment: Ok I will  solve this by some other resources thank you